# What type of spell damage, if any, is associated with fey creatures?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage-types, feywild

Like necrotic damage is related to the undead (and fiends?), is there a equivalent for the fey? Is force damage (like Eldritch Blast and Magic Missle) used as a catch all, or does damage-type generally depend on the entity?

Context: I am playing an *Oath of the Ancients* paladin in an upcoming campaign and am unsure what to expect from fey opponents. Our party's warlock may take an Arch-fey patron so I've had him in mind as well with this question.

I am playing in DnD 5e!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there's no set damage type, Force Damage and Psychic Damage from illusions are the most common types of damage from Fey, followed by radiant and fire, such as from Eladrin.

Fey are associated with sleep, charm, invisibility, teleport, illusion, and magic resistance. Most of their attacks are saving throws.

The Enchantment/Charm school of magic, and the Illusion Phantasm school are popular with fey, and when attacking magically, directly, it's typically raw magical unaligned non elemental energy, or some optical or fire effect.

Just look at the Warlock Archfey list for examples:

1st: faerie fire, sleep;
2nd: calm emotions, phantasmal force;
3rd: blink, plant growth;
4th: dominate beast, greater invisibility;
5th: dominate person, seeming

Answer (score 9):

There is no damage type specifically associated with fey. The only other type that is associated with a creature type is radiant damage with celestials.